# python scrapy: spider follows links but won't download images

Tags: python, scrapy

I've built a basic a crawlspider to scrape the comic images from xkcd and follow links to each comic and continue scraping. The spider follows links just fine but I'm having trouble actually scraping the image.

I've tried multiple xpath and css selectors and ways of writing the parse_item method but I'm either getting errors due to scrapy trying to use the first letter of the url as the full url, or unhashable type 'list' errors and have run out of ideas.

Spider:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule


class XkcdSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'xkcd'
    allowed_domains = ['xkcd.com']
    start_urls = ['http://xkcd.com/']

    rules = (
    Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=r'\/\d{4}\/', unique=True),
         callback='parse_item', follow=True),
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        i = {}
        relative_url = response.xpath(
            '//*[@id="comic"]/img/@src').extract_first()

        absolute_url = response.urljoin(relative_url)
        i['image_urls'] = absolute_url
        return i
```

Items:

```
import scrapy


class XkcdItem(scrapy.Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    # name = scrapy.Field()
    images = scrapy.Field()
    image_urls = scrapy.Field()
```

Image pipeline is set up like this:

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
   'scrapy.pipelines.images.ImagesPipeline': 1,
}
```

Traceback is either this:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Or this:

```
ValueError: Missing scheme in request url: h
```

Which I understand is from scrapy trying to use the first letter of the url rather than the whole thing but I can't find a way to make it work, have tried just `.extract()` rather than `extract_first()` but that doesn't work.

Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: can you do `import logging` and `logging.info(absolute_url)` to see if links are correctly being grabbed?

Comment: Just tried your suggestion and got outputs like this

Comment: where I can see your output?

Comment: [root] INFO: https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/state_borders.png
Does this look right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this

```
srcs = response.xpath('//*[@id="comic"]/img/@src').extract()
i['image_urls'] = [response.urljoin(src) for src in srcs]
```

Probably you've already have done this but, just in case, be sure to set correctly the `IMAGES_STORE` setting.

Comment: Hi, I tried your suggestion and the spider follows links and doesn't produce any errors but doesn't seem to be scraping the images still

Comment: how do your items look when logged?

Comment: Okay, I tried it again and actually wrote `return i` because I forgot to last time I tried and your solution worked! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Upon asking OP about the output of `absolute_url` he replied.

```
[root] INFO: imgs.xkcd.com/comics/state_borders.png Does this look right? –
```

This is incorrect, that is what scraper is telling you, `Missing scheme in request url:` means your URL is missing the HTTP scheme information.

Also provide a list to `dsads` variable.

```
i['image_urls'] = ["https://" + absolute_url] #adding scheme to URL
```

Comment: [root] INFO: https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/obsolete_technology.png
Every time I submit this comment it removes the 'http' part at the start of the url, but it is there `[root] INFO: https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/obsolete_technology.png
`

Comment: The image url you see does that have Http or Https link in the scraper output? If it its http, then its because the image link is redirected to https when opening from browser, but scrapy image pipeline does not handle image link redirects

Comment: If its http, not https, then from your scraper, edit the image url to replace http with https, it should work

Comment: Try to give absolute path to Images_store variable